# How to write a single text file from two different data frame-one has name and second has values using R

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe, text

I have two data Frame. I want to create a single text file. it is an input file for hydrological model Thanks for the help. I tried to write the file code format but it is not accepting. It is also a single column with equal sign. I think given required output file is explaining well.

First data frame is as

```
> lfz
   readLines("G:/Rlearning/wrds.txt")
1                    HYDRUS_Version =
2                         WaterFlow =
3                   SoluteTransport =
4                         Unsatchem =
5                         Unsatchem =
6                               HP1 =
7                     HeatTransport =
8             EquilibriumAdsorption =
9                    MobileImmobile =
10                  RootWaterUptake =
11                       RootGrowth =
12                  MaterialNumbers =
13                 SubregionNumbers =
14                        SpaceUnit =
15                         TimeUnit =
16                       PrintTimes =
17                  NumberOfSolutes =
18                 InitialCondition =
19                    NumberOfNodes =
20                     ProfileDepth =
21                 ObservationNodes =
22                      GridVisible =
23                       SnapToGrid =
24                     ProfileWidth =
25                       LeftMargin =
26                         GridOrgX =
27                         GridOrgY =
28                           GridDX =
29                           GridDY =
```

second data frame is

here 3 represent the row number from a back file that i created and I get the row 3 from it and convert it into column. here values are different. question is simple. I want to write the values after equal sign and want to a text file.

```
> C1    
      3
1     4
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14   cm
15 days
16  160
17    0
18    1
19  101
20  120
21  160
22  160
23  160
24  160
25  160
26  160
27  160
28  160
29  160
```

Required output text file is as

```
HYDRUS_Version=4
WaterFlow=3
SoluteTransport=0
Unsatchem=0
Unsatchem=0
HP1=2
HeatTransport=0
EquilibriumAdsorption=1
MobileImmobile=0
RootWaterUptake=1
RootGrowth=0
MaterialNumbers=1
SubregionNumbers=1
SpaceUnit=cm
TimeUnit=days
PrintTimes=180
NumberOfSolutes=0
InitialCondition=1
NumberOfNodes=101
ProfileDepth=1.2E+02
ObservationNodes=5
GridVisible=1
SnapToGrid=1
ProfileWidth=80
LeftMargin=40
GridOrgX=0
GridOrgY=0
```

Comment: Please correct the format of your question (in particular the Data format) in order to be more user friendly (like they appear in R)

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data!

Comment: probably just `paste` the 2 columns and use `write(..., ncol=1)`...

Comment: > dput(C1)
structure(list(`3` = structure(c(6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", 
"V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", 
"V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20", "V21", "V22", "V23", "V24", 
"V25", "V26", "V27", "V28", "V29"), .Label = c("0", "1", "101", 
"120", "160", "4", "cm", "days"), class = "factor")), .Names = "3", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: > dput(lfz)
structure(list(`readLines("G:/Rlearning/wrds.txt")` = structure(c(9L, 
28L, 23L, 27L, 27L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 21L, 20L, 12L, 25L, 24L, 
26L, 17L, 15L, 10L, 14L, 18L, 16L, 6L, 22L, 19L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("EquilibriumAdsorption =", "GridDX =", "GridDY =", 
"GridOrgX =", "GridOrgY =", "GridVisible =", "HeatTransport =", 
"HP1 =", "HYDRUS_Version =", "InitialCondition =", "LeftMargin =", 
"MaterialNumbers =", "MobileImmobile =", "NumberOfNodes =", "NumberOfSolutes =",

Comment: "ObservationNodes =", "PrintTimes =", "ProfileDepth =", "ProfileWidth =", 
"RootGrowth =", "RootWaterUptake =", "SnapToGrid =", "SoluteTransport =", 
"SpaceUnit =", "SubregionNumbers =", "TimeUnit =", "Unsatchem =", 
"WaterFlow ="), class = "factor")), .Names = "readLines(\"G:/Rlearning/wrds.txt\")", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: data frame lfz I pasted in two parts because its lenth is more than the allowed characters.

Comment: @Cath I am learner of R, I never used the paste option. kindly write it in simple format that I can learn and solve my problem. write the code please with paste or whatever you think for solution. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to paste the strings together, remove the white space and then write it to a file:

```
outVec <- gsub("\\s*", "", paste(lfz[,1], C1[,1])) 
writeLines(outVec, "outfile.txt")
```

Your data should then look like this:

```
HYDRUS_Version=4
WaterFlow=0
SoluteTransport=0
Unsatchem=0
Unsatchem=0
HP1=0
HeatTransport=0
EquilibriumAdsorption=0
MobileImmobile=0
RootWaterUptake=0
RootGrowth=0
MaterialNumbers=0
SubregionNumbers=0
SpaceUnit=cm
TimeUnit=days
PrintTimes=160
NumberOfSolutes=0
InitialCondition=1
NumberOfNodes=101
ProfileDepth=120
ObservationNodes=160
GridVisible=160
SnapToGrid=160
ProfileWidth=160
LeftMargin=160
GridOrgX=160
GridOrgY=160
GridDX=160
GridDY=160
```

Comment: Thanks. I need some more help that How I can learn about these strings. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an example:

Let's create two dataframes:

```
a <- data.frame(col1 = c('a = ','b = ','c = '))
b <- data.frame(col2 = c(1,2,3))

> a
  col1
1 a = 
2 b = 
3 c = 

> b
  col2
1    1
2    2
3    3
```

Let's copy columns from b to a

```
a$col2 <- b$col2
```

Let's concatinate both columns:

```
a$final <- paste0(a$col1, a$col2)
a$col1 <- NULL
a$col2 <- NULL

  final
1 a = 1
2 b = 2
3 c = 3
```

Let's write this down into a file

```
write.csv(a, file = 'output.csv', row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: It is also cool. before that I tried like this but it was not working. Thanks. I need one more help. Now in my final file I want to insert some characters at the specific position??? I want to insert ; \n [Main] in the start then after InitialCondition=1     ;\[Profile]    and then remainig all that will start from NumberOfNodes=101

Comment: @MohsinWaqas Could you edit your original question to show what your output should ultimately look like?